# I'm resigning from moderating on Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, moderation

Considering (not so) recent events that have taken place on Stack Exchange, along with how they're handled (boilerplate response from staff), I am resigning. Things that have happened here make me not want to associate with Stack Exchange, as enforcing a vague CoC before it's even in effect is something I've never seen before, and something to worry about. I wouldn't be happy with that CoC in general, but the way even a hint of dissent (or even genuine curiosity) is treated, I don't think I'd be able to stay around here even if I kept my mouth shut.

This aligns with (yet another) licensing fiasco as well. I'd expect SX and SE to understand that it's not possible to change the license of contributions without consent of authors. It's not the first time it happened, and it seems it faced backlash every single time. That fact alone makes me question the decisions taken by people in charge here.

Moderating here was something I was proud of, and I felt like my time spent moderating here contributed to the community. I hope the remaining moderator is fine with a slightly larger workload.

Comment: What ist your alternative to StackExchange?